# FlashScope.getCurrent(...) always returns new FlashScope instance

Tags: java, web-applications, stripes

Application is based on Stripes & Spring. Every time I call [FlashScope.getCurrent(..)](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/FlashScope.html#getCurrent%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20boolean%29) method the new clean instance of FlashScope is returned. Though if I call [FlashScope.getAllFlashScopes(..)](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/FlashScope.html#getAllFlashScopes%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) I get an array with the FlashScope that was instantiated during previous request and contains all the parameters I stored there. Any thoughts about the reason of that trouble?

Comment: The FlashScope mechanism works by appending an extra parameter to redirect URLs. What are you doing with the flash scope exactly?  What kind of resolution are you returning from the action that creates the scope? It should be a RedirectResolution.

Comment: Yes, I used RedirectResolution. My aim was simply to store the parameter in the FlashScope, I implemented it as the manual says (http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/State+Management).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask this very specific Stripes question on the:

[stripes-users@lists.sourceforge.net](http://www.stripesframework.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=511)
 mailing list